# no such method 'remove' for tabs widget instance

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

We just upgraded our jquery library from 1.8 to 1.11.  With such a big upgrade, it seems there are things breaking.  One of them is the inability to remove tabs anymore from JQuery UI Tabs.

Any help would be appreciated as this no longer works.

```
OBJECT.tabs('remove', 0);
```

I need to remove a tab from JQuery Tabs.

Comment: Looking for something simple, rather than something long handed...

Answer (score 3):

```
OBJECT.find( ".ui-tabs-nav li:eq(0)" ).remove();
OBJECT.tabs( "refresh" );
```